# Consuming webservice from java using CXF results in com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 200: OK

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf

I made wsdl file in Eclipse using WSDL Editor. I made server using CXF (maven plugin way). There is simple function getCities() which I sucessfully called from C#. However I am not able to call it from Java client.

```
@WebResult(name = "out", targetNamespace = "")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "getCities", targetNamespace = "http://www.example.org/BookingServer/", className = "org.example.bookingserver.GetCities")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "getCitiesResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.example.org/BookingServer/", className = "org.example.bookingserver.GetCitiesResponse")
@WebMethod(action = "http://www.example.org/BookingServer/getCities")
public java.util.List<org.example.bookingserver.Cities> getCities();
```

This is way how I call that service (again using Apache-cxf):

```
QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://www.example.org/BookingServer/", "BookingServer");
URL wsdlURL = BookingServer_Service.WSDL_LOCATION;
BookingServer_Service ss = new BookingServer_Service(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
BookingServer port = ss.getBookingServerSOAP();  
java.util.List<org.example.bookingserver.Cities> result = port.getCities();
```

But I get `javax.ejb.EJBException ... Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 200: OK`

I couldnt google anything relevant to this exception.

I tried also using NetBeans webservice client GUI but the exception was same. When I put breakpoint in the server it never breaks. So the problem is in the client.

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that you're not hitting the SOAP endpoint you think you are and instead getting a normal webpage back? I would try putting a proxy in the middle and recording your requests and responses, to see what's going in the HTTP layer.

Comment: You are right. I see that connection goes to www.example.org IP. But how should I force Java to connect to localhost? I generate service client from WSDL made in Eclipse - so it should be specified in wsdl?

Comment: I tried to change soap:address to local URL however I get another exception: `Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Cannot find dispatch method for {http://www.example.org/BookingServer/}getCities Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cuase of the failure.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change soap:address and then the main problem was that I overwrote @WebService annotation of interface generated by CXF by @WebService annotation generated for Webservice when using GUI Wizard. Therefore the location of webservice was different.

Comment: BTW: If you want to change the SE programmatically, you can use

((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, ... );